# Magento2 Wishlist : showing configurable parent image instead of simple product one

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.4, wishlist

I want to show simple product image in whishlist listing.

As of now it show configurable image of product when added in wishlist .

I can not see any option in magento admin for same.

Please help with way for same

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't seem to provide an option for that.

Look like you have to edit the template which renders the image.

Here is the code: Magento_Wishlist::item/column/image.phtml

Please notice that you have to write the logic to change the image yourself